# How to install Biztalk 2013 Project Templates in Visual Studio 2012?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, biztalk, biztalk-2013

Doing some work on a proof of concept in Azure VM with SQL Server 2012, BizTalk 2013 and Visual Studio 2012. All 3 (SQL, BizTalk and Visual Studio) are on the same VM. In visual studio 2012, I cannot see any project templates for BizTalk.

I installed the [Windows Azure BizTalk Services preview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh689760.aspx) but unfortunately, that only installs two templates both for BizTalk Azure services (not orchestrations, etc.).

I tried running (as admin) `devenv.exe /InstallVSTemplates` to no avail.

All I'm trying to do is have the BizTalk project templates installed in VS2012 so I can create an orchestration.

Ideas? Suggestions?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As part of the Biztalk installation, there's an option to install the developer tools and SDK. If it's not installed initially, you can go into control panel, modify the installation and add it there.

If the dev tools and SDK are grayed out, it's because IIS ASPNET 4.5 and WCF HTTP ACTIVATION 4.5 prerequisites have not been met. Ironically enough, once you meet said requirements, they'll appear during installation (as seen in the image below). In order enable the SDK option, I've found that installing Excel, in addition to several IIS options will enable the installation option. Credit to this [blog](http://connectedenterprise.wordpress.com/2012/11/12/how-to-install-a-biztalk-2013-beta-development-environment/) entry for pointing me in the right direction.

[image: BizTalk Installation]

**TL;DR** Install Visual Studio 2012 FIRST to get ASPNET 4.5 and WCF HTTP requirements met before installing BizTalk. Not sure why they couldn't just say something during the BizTalk installation. Maybe have a "Development environment" mode or type of installation where they'd mention having VS installed first.

Comment: Please note that you need Visual Studio 2012 or earlier (not 2013) to be installed first before to enable the SDK and Development Tools option. If you install it after installing BizTalk, you can modify the BizTalk installation to include the SDK and Dev Tools as well, just know that Visual Studio 2012 is supported, NOT 2013.

Comment: Yes and seemingly a waste of time. You'd think BizTalk + SQL Server and Visual Studio would work out of the box. Apparently not. #scarredforlife

Comment: And now I can't get VS2012 installed.  Neat!

Comment: Note too that express versions do not work. You can install a 30 day trial (extendible to 90 days) for free. I found the trial worked to enable the developer tool installation.